# Extraction affine transformation while using rasterio.features.rasterize

Tags: rasterio, rasterization, rioxarray, geocube

I am currently using `rasterio.features.rasterize` to rasterize my shapefile.
But currently I am always using an Rasterfile to a) rasterize and b) save on disk. The get the information of the transformation of the old file and the shape. etc.

Is there a way to circumvent this problem. For I now the resolution I want to have, from the shape files I know the crs and I should be able to get a start position, and maybe even the best orientation?
I am currently trying to write some code I want to containerize and the raster file is some extra huge amount of data, I don't really need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great tool for this is [geocube](https://github.com/corteva/geocube). It will rasterize each of the columns in your shapefile (or a subset if you specify it).

Some examples of usage are listed [here](https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/examples/examples.html)

It can be as simple to use as:

```py
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube

input_shp = "path_to_file.shp"

out_grid = make_geocube(
    vector_data=input_shp,
    resolution=(-0.0001, 0.0001),
)

out_grid["column_name"].rio.to_raster("my_rasterized_column.tif")
```

Comment: I wrote function arround it: 
`def vector2xarray(vector, selection_col, save_path = None,
                  resolution = (-10, 10)) :

    if type(vector) == str:
        gdf = geopandas.read_file(vector)
    elif type(vector) == geopandas.GeoDataFrame:
        gdf = vector
    else:
        raise AttributeError

    out_grid = make_geocube(vector_data=gdf, group_by=selection_col, resolution=resolution)

    if save_path:
        out_grid.rio.to_raster(save_path)

    return out_grid` Problem: the ram usage is much to high and I can't profile it!

Comment: Side note - `make_geocube` accepts a path to the vector data or a geodataframe.

Comment: Also, I think `measurements` is the column you want instead of `group_by`: https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/geocube.html#make-geocube

Comment: yeah, the parameter did the trick. Now the sulting file size is much to large, because the outputs datatype is **float64**, **uint16** would be enough. Besides, I made three raster and concatinated them. Is it possible to concatinate so that, the result **datatype** is **(uint8, uint16, uint16)**, if not **(uint16, uint16, uint16)**?

Comment: You can add that to the `to_raster` command `to_raster(dtype="uint16")`.

Comment: Comment: To be able to use to_raster(dtype="uint16") for the dataarray I had to se the parameter fill for the make_geocube function. I used fill=0.